# Ensime remote debugging

Tags: emacs, ensime

Is it possible to attach ensime debugger to a remote process? I cannot find anything relevant in the manual.

http://aemoncannon.github.com/ensime/index.html

Answer (score 4):

ensime-db-attach prompts for a hostname and port. It should allow you to use all of ensime's debugging features on a remote process.